# How to fast cancel Task.AwaitAll for larger batches

Tags: c#, task, cancellation

Suppose I have a snippet like:

```
public async Task WorkItem(WorkItem workItem, CancellationToken token) {
  Logger.Log("Starting...");
  token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}

public async Task BatchProcessor(IList<WorkItem> workItems, CancellationToken token) {
  var tasks = workItems.Select(wi => WorkItem(wi, token)).ToList();
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

This works great - problem is the code is supposed to cancel fast when cancellation token is retrieved (for service fabric shutdown scenario) - and when you cancel tasks one-by-one you actually enter method body before you hit the exception throwing part - which is an issue when you have lot of work items.

I was thinking of something like

```
var task = Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, token);
await Task.WhenAny(new List<Task> { task, Task.WhenAll(tasks) });
```

Which actaully finishes the method fast once cancellation token is received, but doesn't solve the problem of shutdown vs new tasks popping in.

I guess the proper solution is some kind of partitioner - is there something like that for tasks ?

Comment: Whenever I see a list of things to be processed in parallel, I think of PLinq's `AsParallel()`. Did you try that? It might do a better job than rolling your own version of it. You can pass a CancellationToken.

Comment: @nvoigt - care to formulate it as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @nvoigt suggest solution is rather simple with using parallel Linq. Modified query looks like:

```
var tasks = workItems.AsParallel().WithCancellation(token).Select(wi => WorkItem(wi, token));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Which then cancels much more promptly.